# Did Mongrel restart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, redmine, mongrel

This is the log code , but I have no idea if it restarted or not, How Am I supposed to know?
What language is this?

**Log file**

```
Wed Oct 10 11:41:38 -0400 2012: REQUEST DATA: "\r\n\r\n"
---
PARAMS: {}
---
** INT signal received.
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3001
** Starting Rails with production environment...
** Mounting Rails at /redmine...
** Rails loaded.
** Loading any Rails specific GemPlugins
** Loading C:\\BitNami/apps/redmine\\scripts\\mongrel_rails_envvars external config script
** Signals ready.  INT => stop (no restart).
** Mongrel 1.1.5 available at 0.0.0.0:3001
** Use CTRL-C to stop.
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:19: warning: already initialized constant UnknownFileType
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:126: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromExt
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:132: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromShebang
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:138: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromName
** INT signal received.
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3001
** Starting Rails with production environment...
** Mounting Rails at /redmine...
** Rails loaded.
** Loading any Rails specific GemPlugins
** Loading C:\\BitNami/apps/redmine\\scripts\\mongrel_rails_envvars external config script
** Signals ready.  INT => stop (no restart).
** Mongrel 1.1.5 available at 0.0.0.0:3001
** Use CTRL-C to stop.
Mon Oct 15 11:05:14 -0400 2012: Read error: #<Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.>
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:137:in `write'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:137:in `write'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:103:in `send_body'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:147:in `finished'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:165:in `process_client'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:281
C:/BitNami/ruby/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
C:/BitNami/ruby/bin/mongrel_rails:19
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:19: warning: already initialized constant UnknownFileType
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:126: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromExt
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:132: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromShebang
C:/BitNami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coderay-1.0.6/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:138: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromName
Mon Oct 15 15:05:02 -0400 2012:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a language, it's simply log/console output from the Mongrel app, including some error stack information the same as you would find anywhere else in Ruby.

The giveaway to discern whether Mongrel is starting can be found right here: `** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3001` - that indicates that an instance of Mongrel is starting listening on port 3001. As far as I am aware, two instances can't use the same port at the same time so the log above, where that start-up line appears twice, indicates a restart.